# matlab fmincon calling from c++

Tags: c++, matlab, optimization

I am trying to call Matlab's `fmincon` function from c++. I am using the call

```
mxcallMatlab(2, &arg1, 4, &arg2, "fmincon");
```

where `arg2"`is a Matlab `mxArray` array of dimension 4 (i.e. it is defined as `mxArray *arg2[4]`). `arg2` takes in the 4 different argument to `fmincon`. `arg2[0]` should be the objective function handle which `fmincon` uses as its first argument.
The question is how do I pass the objective function handle to `arg2[0]`. 
My objective function is not defined in Matlab, but in c++. Shall I cast my objective function pointer to double (this I have to do because all inputs to Matlab are double), and then pass that to `arg2[0]`?

Comment: i think the question is not very clear for anyone to understand. Can u edit the post and be more descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

As found [here](http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/answers/44778):

> Only MATLAB can invoke MATLAB function handles. Function handles in
>   MATLAB are a data structure that include (amongst other things) a
>   reference to a data block that stores MATLAB code in a pre-parsed
>   threaded-interpreter format that needs to be interpreted by the MATLAB
>   Engine. MATLAB .m code does not compile down to machine language, only
>   to linked data structures.

So you cannot achieve what you want, as directly as you want it. You'll have to define the objective function in a separate MEX file, define a function handle to it in Matlab to it, and pass that on to the MEX where you call `fmincon`. So, something like

```
[sol, fval, ...] = your_main_mex(@your_objective_mex, ...)
```